WordPress Shipment
I am trying to set up an e commerce website. Now I'm trying to set up the shipment settings. My problem is that I want to sell some products that are really heavy. Therefore I want to set up a special shipment for these products. For example;
-Pick up from store -Free Shipment via Shipment Firm.
The normal products show these two options for the customer.
But for the heavy products I want the second option to vanish and the new options will be : -Pick up from store -Charged Shipping
I want these two options to show up when the heavy products are added to the list or bought exclusively.
Can I do this by coding with in coding snipetts or are there any options that you can suggest me ?
I kindly request your help. Thanks for your interest and time.
I already set up the shipping choices. But I couldn't find a solution for my problem.
